# Cyclic dependency between classes in object oriented design

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am stuck with implementing one of design since it has cyclic dependency. I need to generate a shapes report as per below code snippet and I thought of implementing this as separating as Shape classes which implements common `IShape` interface and Language classes which implements common `ILanguage` interface.

This way any shape will tell its name itself but it doesn't know about language, and if language tells any shape's name then it doesn't know about shape type and also if it is a single shape or collection of shapes.

But report is generated based on total number of Shapes so there seems to be circular dependency between both groups.

```
public string PrintShape(List<Shape> shapes, string language)
{
    string returnString = "";

    if (shapes.Count == 0)
    {
        returnString = (language == "EN") ? "Empty list of shapes" : "Lege lijst van vormen";
    }
    else
    {
        returnString += (language == "EN") ? "Shapes report: " : "Samenvatting vormen: ";

        int numberSquares = 0, numberCircles = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < shapes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (shapes[i].type == "SQUARE")
            {
                numberSquares++;
            }
            if (shapes[i].type == "CIRCLE")
            {
                numberCircles++;
            }
        }

        if (language == "EN")
        {
            returnString += numberSquares + ((numberSquares == 1) ? "Square " : "Squares ");
            returnString += numberCircles + ((numberCircles == 1) ? "Circle " : "Circles ");
        }
        else
        {
            returnString += numberSquares + ((numberSquares == 1) ? "Vierkant " : "Vierkanten ");
            returnString += numberCircles + ((numberCircles == 1) ? "Cirkel " : "Cirkels ");
        }

        returnString += (language == "EN") ? "TOTAL: " : "TOTAAL: ";
        returnString += (numberCircles + numberSquares) + " " + (language == "EN" ? "shapes" : "vormen");
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

Here I have simplified this method with Object Oriented Design.

Below is the code snippet for language implementation:

```
public interface ILanguage { string TotalText { get; } /*..& few others..*/ }

public class English : ILanguage
{
    public string TotalText { get { return "TOTAL:"; } /*..& few others..*/ }
}

public class Dutch : ILanguage
{
    public string TotalText { get { return "TOTAAL:"; } /*..& few others..*/ }
}
```

And here is for shapes implementation:

```
public interface IShape { double Area();    }

public class Square : IShape
{
    public double Area() { /*..area calculation..*/; }
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    public double Area() { /*..area calculation..*/; }
}
```

Now report method PrintShape will get simplified as below:

```
public string PrintShape(List<IShape> shapes, ILanguage language)
{
    string returnString = "";

    if (shapes.Count > 0)
    {
        returnString += language.ReportText;

        int numberSquares = shapes.OfType<Square>().Count();
        int numberCircles = shapes.OfType<Circle>().Count();

        /*..this part is dependent..*/
        if (language == "EN")
        {
            returnString += numberSquares + ((numberSquares == 1) ? "Square " : "Squares ");
            returnString += numberCircles + ((numberCircles == 1) ? "Circle " : "Circles ");
        }
        else
        {
            returnString += numberSquares + ((numberSquares == 1) ? "Vierkant " : "Vierkanten ");
            returnString += numberCircles + ((numberCircles == 1) ? "Cirkel " : "Cirkels ");
        }
        /*..this part is dependent..*/

        returnString += language.TotalText;
        returnString += shapes.Count + " " + language.ShapesText;
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

But still I am not able to decide how to get the text `Circle`, `Circles`, `Square` or `Vierkanten` etc. since language class will not know for which type of shape the text is needed.
Also if language class has to tell the shape/shapes text then adding a new shape will require to modify each language class.

Now if taking other-way, shape should tell its name then it will not know in which language it should be.

So there is a cyclic type dependency between both the classes and I am unable to decide how to implement it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The way your question is written, it is difficult to tell exactly what problem you are having. The title implies that you have a "cyclic dependency", but your method does not recursively call itself, so it is not clear why that would be the case. Please edit your question to clarify what problem you are having - that is, what result you are getting and what the **expected** result is. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need advice on this.

Comment: What you are asking is quite unclear. Since you mentioned cyclic dependencies, it would be really helpful if you could share the code for both the classes or a screenshot of the Solution Explorer tab so that we know where the mentioned classes are located within the project. For now, if I were to assume that you have both the classes in separate projects (hence the circular dependency), you need to add references of these projects to a third project and call both the classes from there.

Comment: Maybe add a list of inputs and your expected string output to help us understand. Perhaps we can provide you with a better solution altogether.

Comment: Still waiting for someone to help on this.